# Como logar somente usuários ativos?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, laravel-auth

Na autenticação além dos dados necessários para logar o usuário, quero que somente os que estão com status `ativo = 1` faça login, mas não sei como fazer esta verificação.

**table user:**

```
id
username
email
password
ativo
```

**UserController**

```php
public function store()
{
      $userdata = array(
          'email'    => Input::get('email'),
          'password' => Input::get('password')
      );
      $rules = array(
          'email'    => 'required',
          'password' => 'required'
      );
      $message = array(
         'email.required'    => 'O :attribute é obrigatório.',
         'password.required' => 'A senha é obrigatória.'
        );
      $validator = Validator::make($userdata, $rules, $message);

     if ($validator->passes())
      {
       if (Auth::attempt($userdata))
          {
           return Redirect::to('')->with('success', 'You have logged in successfully');
          }
          else
          {
           return Redirect::route('admin.create')->withErrors(array('password' => 'Senha inválida'))->withInput(Input::except('password'));
          }
      }

  // Something went wrong.
  return Redirect::route('admin.create')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::except('password'));
```

}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Passa o terceiro parametro que é correspondente a sua coluna de status (ativo ou inativo, exemplifiquei como `activated`):

```php
 $userdata = array(  
      'email'     => Input::get('email'),  
      'password'  => Input::get('password'),  
      'activated' => 'A'  
  );
```

O Laravel adicionará o `activated` ao `where` no momento de localizar o usuário, caso o mesmo esteja inativo não trará.

Comment: Muito obrigado Flávio H. Ferreira.

Answer (score 1):

Outra maneira seria assim:

```
        if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password')), Input::has('lembar') ? true : false)) {
            if(Auth::user()->status == TRUE) {
                return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
            } else {
                Auth::logout();
                return Redirect::route('entrar')->withErrors('Desculpe, mas o Usuário está desativado.');
            }

        } else {
            return Redirect::route('entrar')->withErrors('Usuário ou Senha Inválido.');
        }
```

Comment: Oi, Marcus, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. É legal dar uma explicação, ainda que breve, de porquê seu código resolve o problema. O guia [answer] tem mais detalhes.